# Data Model file has a grey box covering the entities

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have been unable to edit the Core Data Model file from XCode for the last 2 weeks cause there's a grey box covering the entities.

I tried the public version of XCode as well as XCode 12.2 Beta 2 and 3

[image]

Comment: It’s a bug in Xcode. The only work around is to switch to the graph view.

Comment: @TomHarrington nice, that's doing the trick for now thanks